# fill a range on times in Column B for each date in Column A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to generate something like this in excel. For each date in 'Date ' column, I need to fill times between 13:00 and 22:00 with 15 minute intervals. Note: The dates in Column D are not serial. They have to be taken from a list which can reside in another column/worksheet.
Any help is appreciated on this.

```
Date, Time
1 apr-2013, 13:00
1-apr-2013, 13:15
..
..
..
1-apr-2013, 22:00
2-apr-2013, 13:00
..
2-apr-2013, 22:00
8-apr-2013, 13:00
.
8-apr-2013, 22:00
```

Comment: whut? (that's my abbreviation for "what have you tried" which I'm hoping will start to catch on here at stackoverflow)

Comment: i tried the auto fill functionality (i know its silly). Auto fill would have worked if the dates were serial. But dates have to be from a list. Thats where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This formula may work for you. It will check to see if the date in the previous row is equal to the date in the current row; if it is not, then it will set the time as your start time (13:00). If it is, then it adds 15 minutes to the time above the current row.

```
=IF(A2<>A1,TIME(13,0,0),B1+TIME(0,15,0))
```

This formula can be placed next to all of your dates (in the time column)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the DateAdd function in VBA.
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php

For example, this would copy the date in cell A1 to A2 and add 15 minutes to it

```
Range("A2") = DateAdd("n", 15, Range("A1"))
```

Comment: Thanks for that and sounds good. But the real question is dates in column have to be taken from a list of dates specified in a list /column somewhere else against them being serial. How to achieve the same.